SSH Connection to Multipass VM running on remote dedicated server
I have Multipass VMs running on a dedicated server.
Presently to access the VMs, from my local pc, I first ssh into the dedicated server and then use multipass shell vm-name to ssh into the VM.
How can I ssh directly into the multipass vm from my local pc?
Thank you.

I have not used multipass for a long time. When I did, it was only to see what it was. If I remember correctly, the command multipass shell vm-name does not use the ssh protocol. To directly ssh into the Multipass VM, you have to make sure the ssh-server is running inside the Multipass VM, and the VM has an IP address that is accessible from outside the dedicated (host) server.
